# Find an unbiased estimator for theta

Tags: expected-value, unbiased-estimator

The random variable $X$ assumes values 1; 2; 3 with probabilities:
$P(X = 1) = \theta^2$
$P(X = 2) = 2\theta (1-\theta ),\quad 0 < \theta < 1$
$P(X = 3) = (1 -\theta)^2$:
If in a random sample of size $n$, the value 1 is obtained $N_1$ times and the value 2 is obtained $N_2$ times, is $T = (2N_1 + N_2)/2n$ an unbiased estimator of $\theta$?

My attempt:
N1(theta^2)+N2(2theta(1-theta))/n but this does not simplify to T and I also do not know whether one should consider when X=3, I'm also slightly confused about how one goes about finding an unbiased estimator

Comment: Include the self study tag.

Comment: This question does not ask you to find an unbiased estimator: it only asks you to determine whether this particular one is unbiased.  To do so, apply whatever definitions or characterizations of "unbiased estimator" you have learned.